# How can I make touches fall through a layout in the WindowManager, but allow a button in the layout to be interacted with?

Tags: android, android-layout

I currently have a `RelativeLayout` added to the `WindowManager` with the following layout parameters:

```
new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

I would like to add a button to the `RelativeLayout` such that the button can be hit, but all other touches should fall through the `RelativeLayout` and into the activity of the application.

If I use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` as a flag for the `WindowManger.LayoutParams` of the `RelativeLayout`, the touches do fall through, but then I cannot interact with the button because the touches fall through it as well.

Is this possible? What kind of flags do I need to set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a different solution for my needs - adding a transparent `RelativeLayout` to the root view (`FrameLayout`) of an `Activity`, then setting a `View.OnTouchListener` for this layout to handle the touches.

What I asked for in the question does not seem to be possible and for good reason - it would make writing tapjackers much easier. Not having this capability improves the security of Android devices.